# WSL UBUNTU / Buildozer configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables

Tags: python, android, ubuntu, kivy, buildozer

I try to build an android APK from a Python/Kivy script using WSL UBUNTU and buildozer. I followed all steps provided for the buildozer ([link](https://github.com/kivy/buildozer/blob/master/docs/source/installation.rst)) but the build process always ends with this error message:

```
...
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/home/bergison/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/libffi/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/libffi':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details


  STDERR:

# Command failed: ['/usr/bin/python3', '-m', 'pythonforandroid.toolchain', 'create', '--dist_name=myapp', '--bootstrap=sdl2', '--requirements=python3==3.11.0,kivy==2.2.0', '--arch=arm64-v8a', '--arch=armeabi-v7a', '--copy-libs', '--color=always', '--storage-dir=/home/bergison/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a', '--ndk-api=21', '--ignore-setup-py', '--debug']
# ENVIRONMENT:
#     SHELL = '/bin/bash'
#     WSL_DISTRO_NAME = 'Ubuntu-20.04'
#     NAME = 'FLIEGER'
#     PWD = '/home/bergison'
#     LOGNAME = 'bergison'
#     HOME = '/home/bergison'
#     LANG = 'C.UTF-8'
#     LS_COLORS = 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:'
#     LESSCLOSE = '/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s'
#     TERM = 'xterm-256color'
#     LESSOPEN = '| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s'
#     USER = 'bergison'
#     SHLVL = '1'
#     WSLENV = ''
#     XDG_DATA_DIRS = '/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop'
#     PATH = ('/home/bergison/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/home/bergison/.local/bin:/home/bergison/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/mnt/c/Program '
 'Files/WindowsApps/CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu20.04LTS_2004.6.16.0_x64__79rhkp1fndgsc:/mnt/c/Program '
 'Files (x86)/Common '
 'Files/Oracle/Java/javapath:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/system32:/mnt/c/WINDOWS:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/OpenSSH/:/mnt/c/Program '
 'Files/NVIDIA Corporation/NVIDIA NvDLISR:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA '
 'Corporation/PhysX/Common:/mnt/c/Users/chris/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/Scripts/:/mnt/c/Users/chris/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/:/mnt/c/Users/chris/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/mnt/f/PyCharm/bin:/snap/bin:/home/bergison/.local/bin/')
#     HOSTTYPE = 'x86_64'
#     _ = '/home/bergison/.local/bin/buildozer'
#     PACKAGES_PATH = '/home/bergison/.buildozer/android/packages'
#     ANDROIDSDK = '/home/bergison/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk'
#     ANDROIDNDK = '/home/bergison/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b'
#     ANDROIDAPI = '31'
#     ANDROIDMINAPI = '21'
#
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

This is the content of the config.log:

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by libffi configure 3.4.2, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.69.  Invocation command line was

  $ /home/bergison/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/libffi/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/libffi/configure --host=arm-linux-androideabi --prefix=/home/bergison/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/libffi/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/libffi --disable-builddir --enable-shared

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = FLIEGER
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 4.4.0-19041-Microsoft
uname -s = Linux
uname -v = #3393-Microsoft Mon Aug 14 14:52:00 PST 2023

/usr/bin/uname -p = x86_64
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = x86_64
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /home/bergison/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin
PATH: /home/bergison/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b
PATH: /home/bergison/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk/tools
PATH: /home/bergison/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin
PATH: /home/bergison/.local/bin
PATH: /home/bergison/bin
PATH: /usr/local/sbin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /sbin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /usr/games
PATH: /usr/local/games
PATH: /mnt/c/Program Files/WindowsApps/CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu20.04LTS_2004.6.16.0_x64__79rhkp1fndgsc
PATH: /mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Oracle/Java/javapath
PATH: /mnt/c/WINDOWS/system32
PATH: /mnt/c/WINDOWS
PATH: /mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem
PATH: /mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/
PATH: /mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/OpenSSH/
PATH: /mnt/c/Program Files/NVIDIA Corporation/NVIDIA NvDLISR
PATH: /mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common
PATH: /mnt/c/Users/chris/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/Scripts/
PATH: /mnt/c/Users/chris/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/
PATH: /mnt/c/Users/chris/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps
PATH: /mnt/f/PyCharm/bin
PATH: /snap/bin
PATH: /home/bergison/.local/bin/


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:2703: checking build system type
configure:2717: result: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
configure:2737: checking host system type
configure:2750: result: arm-unknown-linux-androideabi
configure:2770: checking target system type
configure:2783: result: arm-unknown-linux-androideabi
configure:2880: checking for gsed
configure:2911: result: sed
configure:2939: checking for a BSD-compatible install
configure:3007: result: /usr/bin/install -c
configure:3018: checking whether build environment is sane
configure:3073: result: yes
configure:3127: checking for arm-linux-androideabi-strip
configure:3154: result: /home/bergison/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/llvm-strip --strip-unneeded
configure:3219: checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p
configure:3258: result: /usr/bin/mkdir -p
configure:3265: checking for gawk
configure:3281: found /usr/bin/gawk
configure:3292: result: gawk
configure:3303: checking whether make -j16 sets $(MAKE)
configure:3325: result: yes
configure:3354: checking whether make -j16 supports nested variables
configure:3371: result: yes
configure:3516: checking for arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
configure:3543: result: /home/bergison/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang -target armv7a-linux-androideabi21 -fomit-frame-pointer -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp -mthumb -fPIC
configure:3812: checking for C compiler version
configure:3821: /home/bergison/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang -target armv7a-linux-androideabi21 -fomit-frame-pointer -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp -mthumb -fPIC --version >&5
/home/bergison/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/libffi/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/libffi/configure: line 3823: /home/bergison/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
configure:3832: $? = 126
configure:3821: /home/bergison/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang -target armv7a-linux-androideabi21 -fomit-frame-pointer -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp -mthumb -fPIC -v >&5
/home/bergison/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/libffi/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/libffi/configure: line 3823: /home/bergison/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
configure:3832: $? = 126
configure:3821: /home/bergison/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang -target armv7a-linux-androideabi21 -fomit-frame-pointer -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp -mthumb -fPIC -V >&5
/home/bergison/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/libffi/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/libffi/configure: line 3823: /home/bergison/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
configure:3832: $? = 126
configure:3821: /home/bergison/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang -target armv7a-linux-androideabi21 -fomit-frame-pointer -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp -mthumb -fPIC -qversion >&5
/home/bergison/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/libffi/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/libffi/configure: line 3823: /home/bergison/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
configure:3832: $? = 126
configure:3852: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:3874: /home/bergison/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang -target armv7a-linux-androideabi21 -fomit-frame-pointer -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp -mthumb -fPIC -target armv7a-linux-androideabi21 -fomit-frame-pointer -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp -mthumb -fPIC -DANDROID -I/home/bergison/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/include -I/home/bergison/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/armeabi-v7a/include/python3.1   -L/home/bergison/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/libs_collections/myapp/armeabi-v7a conftest.c  >&5
/home/bergison/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/libffi/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/libffi/configure: line 3876: /home/bergison/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
configure:3878: $? = 126
configure:3916: result: no
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "libffi"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "libffi"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "3.4.2"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "libffi 3.4.2"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "http://github.com/libffi/libffi/issues"
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| #define PACKAGE "libffi"
| #define VERSION "3.4.2"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:3921: error: in `/home/bergison/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/libffi/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/libffi':
configure:3923: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
ac_cv_env_CCASFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CCASFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CCAS_set=
ac_cv_env_CCAS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value='-DANDROID -I/home/bergison/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/include -I/home/bergison/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/armeabi-v7a/include/python3.1'
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
ac_cv_env_CXXCPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CXXCPP_value=
ac_cv_env_LT_SYS_LIBRARY_PATH_set=
ac_cv_env_LT_SYS_LIBRARY_PATH_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=set
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=arm-linux-androideabi
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_host=arm-unknown-linux-androideabi
ac_cv_path_ax_enable_builddir_sed=sed
ac_cv_path_install='/usr/bin/install -c'
ac_cv_path_mkdir=/usr/bin/mkdir
ac_cv_prog_AWK=gawk
ac_cv_prog_CC='/home/bergison/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang -target armv7a-linux-androideabi21 -fomit-frame-pointer -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp -mthumb -fPIC'
ac_cv_prog_STRIP='/home/bergison/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/llvm-strip --strip-unneeded'
ac_cv_prog_make_make_set=yes
ac_cv_target=arm-unknown-linux-androideabi
am_cv_make_support_nested_variables=yes

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

ACLOCAL='${SHELL} /home/bergison/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/libffi/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/libffi/missing aclocal-1.16'
ALLOCA=''
AMDEPBACKSLASH=''
AMDEP_FALSE=''
AMDEP_TRUE=''
AMTAR='$${TAR-tar}'
AM_BACKSLASH='\'
AM_DEFAULT_V='$(AM_DEFAULT_VERBOSITY)'
AM_DEFAULT_VERBOSITY='1'
AM_LTLDFLAGS=''
AM_RUNTESTFLAGS=''
AM_V='$(V)'
AR='/home/bergison/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/llvm-ar'
AUTOCONF='${SHELL} /home/bergison/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/libffi/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/libffi/missing autoconf'
AUTOHEADER='${SHELL} /home/bergison/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/libffi/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/libffi/missing autoheader'
AUTOMAKE='${SHELL} /home/bergison/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/libffi/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/libffi/missing automake-1.16'
AWK='gawk'
BUILD_DOCS_FALSE=''
BUILD_DOCS_TRUE=''
CC='/home/bergison/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang -target armv7a-linux-androideabi21 -fomit-frame-pointer -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp -mthumb -fPIC'
CCAS=''
CCASDEPMODE=''
CCASFLAGS=''
CCDEPMODE=''
CFLAGS='-target armv7a-linux-androideabi21 -fomit-frame-pointer -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp -mthumb -fPIC'
CPP=''
CPPFLAGS='-DANDROID -I/home/bergison/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/include -I/home/bergison/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/armeabi-v7a/include/python3.1'
CXX='/home/bergison/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++ -target armv7a-linux-androideabi21 -fomit-frame-pointer -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp -mthumb -fPIC'
CXXCPP=''
CXXDEPMODE=''
CXXFLAGS='-target armv7a-linux-androideabi21 -fomit-frame-pointer -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp -mthumb -fPIC'
CYGPATH_W='echo'
DEFS=''
DEPDIR=''
DLLTOOL=''
DSYMUTIL=''
DUMPBIN=''
ECHO_C=''
ECHO_N='-n'
ECHO_T=''
EGREP=''
EXEEXT=''
FFI_DEBUG_FALSE=''
FFI_DEBUG_TRUE=''
FFI_EXEC_TRAMPOLINE_TABLE=''
FFI_EXEC_TRAMPOLINE_TABLE_FALSE=''
FFI_EXEC_TRAMPOLINE_TABLE_TRUE=''
FGREP=''
GREP=''
HAVE_LONG_DOUBLE=''
HAVE_LONG_DOUBLE_VARIANT=''
INSTALL_DATA='${INSTALL} -m 644'
INSTALL_PROGRAM='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_SCRIPT='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_STRIP_PROGRAM='$(install_sh) -c -s'
LD=''
LDFLAGS='  -L/home/bergison/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/libs_collections/myapp/armeabi-v7a'
LIBFFI_BUILD_VERSIONED_SHLIB_FALSE=''
LIBFFI_BUILD_VERSIONED_SHLIB_GNU_FALSE=''
LIBFFI_BUILD_VERSIONED_SHLIB_GNU_TRUE=''
LIBFFI_BUILD_VERSIONED_SHLIB_SUN_FALSE=''
LIBFFI_BUILD_VERSIONED_SHLIB_SUN_TRUE=''
LIBFFI_BUILD_VERSIONED_SHLIB_TRUE=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBS=''
LIBTOOL=''
LIPO=''
LN_S=''
LTLIBOBJS=''
LT_SYS_LIBRARY_PATH=''
MAINT=''
MAINTAINER_MODE_FALSE=''
MAINTAINER_MODE_TRUE=''
MAKEINFO='${SHELL} /home/bergison/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/libffi/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/libffi/missing makeinfo'
MANIFEST_TOOL=''
MKDIR_P='/usr/bin/mkdir -p'
NM=''
NMEDIT=''
OBJDUMP=''
OBJEXT=''
OPT_LDFLAGS=''
OTOOL64=''
OTOOL=''
PACKAGE='libffi'
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT='http://github.com/libffi/libffi/issues'
PACKAGE_NAME='libffi'
PACKAGE_STRING='libffi 3.4.2'
PACKAGE_TARNAME='libffi'
PACKAGE_URL=''
PACKAGE_VERSION='3.4.2'
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
PRTDIAG=''
RANLIB='/home/bergison/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/llvm-ranlib'
READELF='/home/bergison/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/llvm-readelf'
SECTION_LDFLAGS=''
SED=''
SET_MAKE=''
SHELL='/bin/bash'
STRIP='/home/bergison/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/llvm-strip --strip-unneeded'
TARGET='arm-unknown-linux-androideabi'
TARGETDIR=''
TARGET_OBJ=''
TESTSUBDIR_FALSE=''
TESTSUBDIR_TRUE=''
VERSION='3.4.2'
ac_ct_AR=''
ac_ct_CC=''
ac_ct_CXX=''
ac_ct_DUMPBIN=''
am__EXEEXT_FALSE=''
am__EXEEXT_TRUE=''
am__fastdepCCAS_FALSE=''
am__fastdepCCAS_TRUE=''
am__fastdepCC_FALSE=''
am__fastdepCC_TRUE=''
am__fastdepCXX_FALSE=''
am__fastdepCXX_TRUE=''
am__include=''
am__isrc=''
am__leading_dot='.'
am__nodep=''
am__quote=''
am__tar='$${TAR-tar} chof - "$$tardir"'
am__untar='$${TAR-tar} xf -'
ax_enable_builddir_sed='sed'
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build='x86_64-pc-linux-gnu'
build_alias=''
build_cpu='x86_64'
build_os='linux-gnu'
build_vendor='pc'
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE_TARNAME}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec_prefix='NONE'
host='arm-unknown-linux-androideabi'
host_alias='arm-linux-androideabi'
host_cpu='arm'
host_os='linux-androideabi'
host_vendor='unknown'
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
install_sh='${SHELL} /home/bergison/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/libffi/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/libffi/install-sh'
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
mkdir_p='$(MKDIR_P)'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
pdfdir='${docdir}'
prefix='/home/bergison/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/libffi/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/libffi'
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
psdir='${docdir}'
runstatedir='${localstatedir}/run'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
sys_symbol_underscore=''
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target='arm-unknown-linux-androideabi'
target_alias='arm-linux-androideabi'
target_cpu='arm'
target_os='linux-androideabi'
target_vendor='unknown'
toolexecdir=''
toolexeclibdir=''

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

/* confdefs.h */
#define PACKAGE_NAME "libffi"
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME "libffi"
#define PACKAGE_VERSION "3.4.2"
#define PACKAGE_STRING "libffi 3.4.2"
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "http://github.com/libffi/libffi/issues"
#define PACKAGE_URL ""
#define PACKAGE "libffi"
#define VERSION "3.4.2"

configure: exit 77
```

I'm really stuck on this - ANY HELP IS GREATLY APPRECHIATED! **Thanks!**

I have tried all related hints and troubleshooting I could find, also re-installed UBUNTU and buildozer, but to no avail.